# Change value in a model, adding upon what's written

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called **Dealers**, and there's a bunch of dealers (which contain the value **name**).

And I would like to update all these dealers all at once, but I would like to add the string "__old" to all these Dealers.

I know I could use an `update_all`, but that would change all the value's to __old which is not the objective. Is there a way to update the values, maintaining the old name and adding the new value?

Thanks a lot for your help! Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a little bit of SQL in the `update_all` call like:

```rb
Dealer.update_all(['name = CONCAT(name, ?)', '__old'])
```

Comment: Hello! I've tried it but I get the following error
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, Array passed.)

Comment: That seems like an exception that would come out of `update`.  Are you using `update_all`?  Which version of Rails are you on?  Do you have any overrides of `update_all`?

Comment: It was my bad! I misread it and wrote `update` instead of `update_all` . It works perfectly! Thanks